# Give a model that proves $1*v = v$ is not a redundant axiom

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

So, I need to give a model with form $(E,+,K,·)$ that basically satisfies all the properties of a vector space except: $1·v=v \;\; ∀v∈V$ where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of $K$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: can you see a "trivial" way to define a map $K\times G\rightarrow G$ for any field $K$ and group of "vectors" $G$?

Comment: +1 because I can't come up with a counter example. Should be really trivial, but I can't do it, not completely. One trivial model, $1\star \vec v:=\lambda \vec v$ fails for $\alpha\beta\star \vec v=\alpha\star(\beta\star\vec v)$.

Comment: @GyroGearloose That's not quite right - there's one value of $\lambda$ for which it works . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber actually, I can see two, 0 and 1, but both are *trivial* (in the sens of *not matching the heart of the question*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote your scalar multiplication by $\star$ as in your title. Denote $1\star\vec v:=\omega(\vec v)$ where $\omega$ is necessarily a homomorphism.

Because $\omega(\vec v)=1\star \vec v=1^n\star \vec v=\omega^n(\vec v)$, the mapping $\omega$ needs to be idempotent. Aside from the (obvious) identity (which gives you the standard definition), only projections comply with this, and every projection complies with this.

So for every projection P you can have $\star^P$ that matches your request.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks a lot.